# Android Status Bar icons

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I was using this amazing app 'Medium' for reading posts other day. I noticed an unusual visual effect happening at the status bar. Whenever I used to scroll down the post, the status bar icons were made invisible and some were made dim. I really liked this effect and tried to achieve it in my apps but was unable to do so.

Can someone explain how to do so programmatically?
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It is the feature achievable by **`CollapsingToolbarLayout`** in android.

you may find several examples of this.

First, try to search wisely to understand the topics and google it as well.

Please check all this URL:-

1. https://antonioleiva.com/collapsing-toolbar-layout/
2. http://tutorialsbuzz.com/2015/11/android-collapsingtoolbarlayout-example_7.html
3. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BTYuLho5_rE

Comment: Thanks for giving useless advice. I already knew about collapsing toolbar. I think you haven't got my question. Still thanks.

Comment: I am asking about icons themselves not status bar color changing or something like that

Comment: Then, Please modified your question and be specific with the content by putting screenshots and all. can I ask what type of visual effect you are noticing in the application with icons?